# Visual Studio Compiling C and Assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, visual-studio-2013

I am learning assembly and am having a hard time understanding how to compile a project. I'm trying to follow a textbook example that's kind of cryptic with the exact step by step process to compile. Either that or I'm misunderstanding the flow of data. I am compiling 32 bit code in protected mode with a NASM (Netwide Assembler) and the free GNU gcc compiler (or atleast that's my goal). First question is first, I am hoping that the assembler and compiler are compatible with the ones on Microsoft's Visual Studio Express 2013.

What I have

1. A C driver routine - calls a function (which is written in assembly called asm_main)
2. The first.asm code which defines asm_main as a global variable

Now when I create a project I try to create an empty project (under additional options) after which, I add the C driver file and the .asm file under source files. When I try to compile this I get linking errors, which makes sense because under a different tutorial, it changed some properties and chose (as well as added) the same filepath the files in to 2 different input boxes (under Microsoft Macro Assembler) and Linker options. I'm just unsure and now doubting if the status quo will work for me (since I got errors on compile).

This confusion is mainly arising from the fact that I'm using Visual Studio and the tutorial is asking me to use the command line. It's asking for me to run the code:

```
nasm -f object-format first.asm
```

This line was supposed to assemble the code and output an object file of win32 (since I'm using Visual Studio). The command line (Start-->Run-->Command) says this is not a valid input, this might be because I'm not in the right filepath but it says NASM is not valid which makes me thing there's a setting I'm not configuring.

After this step, I was supposed to compile the C code with:

```
gcc -c driver.c
```

Again this is supposed to be done via command line, but now again `gcc` command that's not recognized by the computer.

Now the next step says I can compile & link with this following code, which I'm assuming makes the code above useless. This line is:

```
gcc -o first driver.c first.o asm_io.o
```

This makes some sense because `driver.c` is the c file needed to be compiled, the file that houses the call to `asm_io.o` however `asm_io.o` is defined inside `first.o` so I'm also confused why you need to include it in the link.

So to summarize my questions are:

- How do you properly link object files to their corresponding C file?
- Specifically how do you compile mixed assembly and C code.
- How do you choose the right filepath for the command line prompt, for those actions as specified in the reference text?
- What is NASM?

Comment: `nasm` and `gcc` are actual executable names. You can't use them without installing them, and they have nothing to do with Visual Studio. (Microsoft's assembler is masm.exe, and it has a different syntax. Microsoft's C compiler is cl.exe, and it isn't directly compatible with gcc.) nasm and gcc are both open-source projects, and you should be able to find them via Google. If you install them properly, the instructions you're following should work. (And just out of curiosity, what does **any** of your question have to do with *Visual Basic*?)

Comment: Did you try to [search for "nasm"](https://www.google.se/search?q=nasm)?

Comment: I do not understand the title of the question with **"Visual Basic"**.  This seems to have nothing at all to do with Basic?

Comment: @Joachim yeah I did but there's a lot of noise out there so I wasn't sure if it was worth the time.

Comment: Well [the first link](http://www.nasm.us/) for me in that search is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @KenWhite I will try and install and see if that works. Will the command prompt be automatically able to process the command thereafter? I got Visual Basic and Visual Studio mixed up... It's difficult to read a full on textbook with no outside help.

Comment: Fine, now you've mentioned Visual Studio instead... but you seem to be using GNU-gcc.  Those usually do not go together.   Did you modify Visual Studio to use GCC?  Are you on Linux or Windows?

Comment: The command prompt will work properly if the PATH is updated correctly during the installation. Make sure you get the proper version (for Windows 32-bit) when you download them, and then     - read and follow the installation instructions carefully, and you should be fine.

Comment: @abelenky I'm on Windows. See the tutorial said we were "compiling 32 bit code in protected mode with a NASM (Netwide Assembler) and the free GNU gcc compiler" However it suggested using Visual Studio Express to create the object code (from the .asm file) to which I could then link and compile the object code with the .exe or even the .c (because I think compiling a .c file returns an .exe - not sure if I have to link before or after ... correct if incorrectly assumed).
Can someone just confirm that I can install to use the GCC compiler and NASM assembler because I think someone said otherwise